# What Redux mean by there is one particular function take the whole state of the application?

Tags: redux, erp

- I just start learning how redux work : 
  What redux mean by there is one particular function take the whole state of the application and action is been dispatched and return the whole new state of the application? 
  is this is visible on Enterprise level application Single Page Application  ERP system or I have misunderstood something?
  also how the function be pure and change in the previous state  " use ref of the previous state and add to it new data then return this as an object? 
  if it is not is that will not affect the speed of the system to copy each time the whole system state for ERP system?

[the course in which I get this info 1](https://egghead.io/lessons/react-redux-pure-and-impure-functions)

[the course in which I get this info 2](https://egghead.io/lessons/react-redux-the-reducer-function)

Comment: Yes, you'll need to return a new state every time. that said, it's not a deep copy of the state. You only need to change the references of the lower part you want to update in the store, and also update the parents' references. Everything else remains the same and thus, you shouldn't really have any perf issues.

Comment: I didn't understand exactly what you mean but update/change the reference?

Answer (score 1):

### Redux in general

In redux, your app's state is represented as a single object which is passed to your app.

This single object is constructed by a single function which is called *reducer*. This function takes the current state and current action as arguments and returns a **new object** which represents the new state changed after the action is *reduced*.

It's kinda similar to `Array.prototype.reduce` where you get current accumulator (current state) current array entry (current action) and return new accumulator (new state) depending on what is the current accumulator and entry (state and action).

### Combining reducers

Nevertheless, this doesn't mean you need to put all of your app's logic in one function. Redux has a helper `combineReducers` to let you write reducers for different parts of your state and then combine them into *single* reducer that constructs a *single* state object.

For example for a blog app with posts and comments, you can use it like that:

```
import { combineReducers, createStore } from 'redux';
import postsReducer from './postReducer';
import commentsReducer from './commentsReducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  posts: postsReducer,
  comments: commentsReducer,
});

const store = createStore(rootReducer);
```

Where `postReducer` and `commentsReducer` are two separate reducers each handling their part of the state.